# textarea_html not working with Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress

I use WordPress 4.9.2 with Visual Composer 5.1
I want to add text editor on VC but it is not working

```
vc_map( array(
    "name" => esc_html__("SNS Test",'themeles'),
    "base" => "sns_test",
    "icon" => "sns_icon_test",
    "class" => "sns_test",
    "category" => esc_html__("SNS Test",'themeles'),
    "description" => esc_html__( "test ",'themeles' ),
    "params" => array(
          array(
            "type" => "textarea_html",
            "class" => "",
            "heading" => esc_html__("Description",'snsanton'),
            "param_name" => "product_excerpt",
            "value" => "",
            "description" => esc_html__("Custom the description for the 
              product.", 'snsanton'),
        ),
      .....
  ));
```

text doesn't save HTML not working like strong or I

Comment: VisualComposer have both `text editor` and `html importing`.

Comment: Is it above code you are adding i vc ?

Answer (score 9):

It does not work because your param name needs to be "`content`".

[The documentation says this](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VC/pages/524332/vc+map#vc_map()-Availabletypevalues):

> Text area with default WordPress WYSIWYG Editor. Important: only one html textarea is permitted per shortcode and it should have "content" as a param_name

Comment: So is there a way to make a VC component that uses the tinymce editor and feature a title? Would an approach be to register 2 shortcodes and combine them? Could you help me?

Comment: Yes, you  can add another array to the params array for the title;

This is how I build all the custom modules for Visual Composer. I just put this file together, there might be some things that need to be changed.

https://github.com/MihaiSlujitoru/WPBakery-Modules/blob/master/example.php

Comment: I see, ive figured most of it out, only i cant get the url to show once you click the save changes button. It shows up in the modal/dialog  like URL: http://localhost/page-name but not beyond that.. Any clue? must be the markup.. Ive posted my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675012/display-post-url-nice-in-wordpress-admin-visual-composer-custom-component

Comment: Super helpful. And for anyone else, the param_name content is then used in the shortcode template as the $content, not as an attribute and not needing to be specified via shortcode_atts().

Comment: The most stupid limitation i ever seen. Except for the whole Wordpress.